# zoom out no horizontal bar

Tags: css

Our [website](http://www.mindef.gov.sg) has an HTML issue when we use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> to enlarge the page view, there’s no horizontal scroll bar in the browser.

I tried to add a CSS rule `body {overflow-x:auto;}`, but, after that, the content will be cut and the menu will become weird.

Can someone help me fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got an "overflow-x:hidden" in your html tag in your css. remove that and you should be good to go. Its in "static.css" line no. 4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I still have to wrap the whole content into a div with a constant width. For browser compatibility. Thank you the same.